# Fill a column in a data frame only one step up

Tags: r

I want to fill one step up with one variable in a data frame

```
> id <- rep(1:3,each=2)
> trt <- rep(c("A","B"),3)
> score <- c("1", "","", 3, "",6)

> df <- data.frame(id,trt,score)
> df
  id trt score
1  1   A     1
2  1   B      
3  2   A      
4  2   B     3
5  3   A      
6  3   B     6
> 

I want it to look like this:

    > id <- rep(1:3,each=2)
    > trt <- rep(c("A","B"),3)
    > score <- c(1, "",3, 3, 6,6)
    > df <- data.frame(id,trt,score)
    > df
      id trt score
    1  1   A     1
    2  1   B      
    3  2   A     3
    4  2   B     3
    5  3   A     6
    6  3   B     6
```

I know this code fill in the columns up, but I just want it to fill one step up, is that possible to do?

```
 library(tidyr)
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% fill(score, .direction="up")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `fill` we need `NA`'s while you have empty string values. We can conditional replace blank values with `NA` for only one row above non-blank values and then use `fill`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(score = replace(score, which(score != "") - 1, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(score, .direction = "up")

#  id trt score
#1  1   A     1
#2  1   B      
#3  2   A     3
#4  2   B     3
#5  3   A     6
#6  3   B     6
```

---

An alternative and simple base R option would be

```
inds <- which(df$score != '')
inds <- inds[inds > 1]
df$score[inds - 1] <- df$score[inds]
```